# Handle Boolean like boolean for Getter/Setter generation

Tags: java, lombok

We want to achieve that the `Boolean` are handled like `boolean` with lombok Getters/Setters when their name starting with an "is"-prefix. Is there a way to do so with lombok?

We always use the "is"-prefix for our member variables in Java (as well in SQL and JavaScript) as a coding convention. With `boolean` types we are very happy with default lombok behaviour for getters/setters. Now we want to achieve the same generation logic for `Boolean`s as well, but the lombok default is a different between `boolean` and `Boolean`.

I tried the following:

```
@Data
public class BooleanChallenge {
    // @Getter @Setter just work fine for boolean
    private boolean isSmallBoolean;

    // Boolean are handled different
    private Boolean isBigBoolean;

    @Accessors(fluent = true)
    private Boolean isFluentAccessor;

    @Accessors(prefix = "is")
    private Boolean isWithPrefix;

    @Accessors(prefix = "is", fluent = true)
    private Boolean isWithPrefixAndFluent;

    private void useThoseGetterzAndSetterz() {
        this.isSmallBoolean(); // ✔ "is"-prefix for getter
        this.setSmallBoolean(true); // ✔ "set"-prefix for setter

        this.getIsBigBoolean(); // ❌ "get is"
        this.setIsBigBoolean(true); // ❌ "set is"

        this.isFluentAccessor(); // ✔
        this.isFluentAccessor(true); // ❌ "is"-prefix instead of "get" prefix

        this.getWithPrefix(); // ❌ no "is"-prefix
        this.setWithPrefix(true); // ✔

        this.withPrefixAndFluent(); // ❌
        this.withPrefixAndFluent(true); // ❌
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your actual question? If you have a remark or improvement suggestion about Lombok, why not notify the Lombok team of that? But maybe they have a reason not to follow the "is.." reasoning? Nothing is stopping you from adding them manually

Comment: Having "is" prefix for Boolean fields would be against the JavaBeans specification.
You may have problems with such accessor methods even if you write them manually.

Answer (score 2):

Here is some stuff.

1. <s>Don't prefix your `boolean` field.
   That is terrible and ridiculous because,
   the JavaBean spec states that the getter for a `boolean` field must be named
   `isFieldName`, which becomes `isIsBlammy()`.
   Stop using a terrible practice as your convention.</s>
   It seems that terrible is here to stay.
   Also, Lombok recognizes terrible and generates correct getter methods
   (`isBlammy()` in the example).
2. The correct (JavaBean spec compliant) name of the getter for a `Boolean`
   (note the capital 'B') field is `getFieldName`.
   this is intentional and is not a mistake.
   Lombok generates compliant getter methods.
3. Java autoboxes and autounboxes between primatives and non-primatives
   (in this case, between boolean and Boolean).
   When you have a getter that returns boolean and you assign the return value
   to a Boolean variable,
   Java automatically generates the correct Boolean value for the assignment.

The only time you need `Boolean` is when `null` is a valid value (i.e. can happen).
If fluentAccessor can never be null,
change it to be `boolean` an autoboxing will solve your issue.

When `null` is a legit possible value,
`Boolean` is appropriate and `boolean` is not an option.

**Additional stuff**

Since changing the terrible naming convention is not an option,
you must create the getter yourself.

Here is an example:

```
// Disable the Lombok getIsHooty method creation.
@Getter(AccessLevel.NONE)
private Boolean isHooty;

public Boolean isHooty()
{
    return isHooty;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but that's not a solution for us.
The naming convention with starting "is" for boolean methods and variables was used by Sun for the Java core packages.

Using the is prefix solves a common problem of choosing bad boolean names like status or flag. isStatus or isFlag simply doesn't fit, and the programmer is forced to chose more meaningful names.

Comment: Let go of the "naming convention" concerns.  Lombok will not generate isBlammy for a `Boolean blammy` field.

Comment: Treating `Boolean` variables the same way as `boolean` variables is asking for trouble. Moreover, as DwB already mentions, that naming convenitions breaks the Java Bean Specification so it will cause tons of issues with libraries that rely on that (JSON/XML converters, for example).
Lombok does not help you generate that kind of code, and I don't think you will be able to convince the authors to change it to do so. With reason.

Answer (score 1):

Here are my 50 cents: `boolean` is binary/dual-state, whereas `Boolean` is ternary/tri-state, as it takes `true`, `false` and `null`, or to be more precise, `Boolean.TRUE`, `Boolean.FALSE`, any self-created object, and `null`.

When one has a function `isSomething` you expect it to return either true or false, not null. So a possible `null` value might screw something up big-time.

That being said, I cannot really help you with your actual problem. What I can suggest is that you enhance the Lombok library so that it creates functions that convert the `Boolean` return values into `boolean`s, with some default annotation for `default-if-null` and default `false-if-null` behavior. But this approach with the 'hidden conversion' already looks quite hackish. A bit much just to keep up coding conventions.